# Titanium alloy controller working with Appcelerator App Designer?

Tags: appcelerator, designer, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am created one sample alloy app in appcelerator studio.
Designed UI in **controller(.js)** not in **xml**.
So how can I use appcelerator app designer for alloy controllers(.js).

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks for trying out the App Designer! Really appreciate all your feedback on your experience as we continue to improve upon it! Now to your question -

Appcelerator Designer (still in Beta) allows you to design the view of your application specifically. Any UI created from the controller is considered dynamic and not part of the actual View layout.

Don't be discouraged here though. This is really about helping to enforce some best practices. When creating UI, its best to break down the parts. If you are creating a new UI component, something you might do from the controller, consider creating a new Alloy View/controller and using this as an element. In doing so, the Designer can help with that design and you can then create that view dynamically using

```
var myView = Alloy.createController('myUiElement", {property:'someProperty');
```

Hope this helps, and all the best with your app!